# p4 diff2 not showing difference of two files

Tags: python, perforce, p4v

I'm using P4 python version, and tried to get the difference of two files. However, it only returns filename and version.

```
l=p4.run("diff2","//a/b/c.h#42","//a/b/c.h#11")
print(l)
```

and the output is

```
[{'status': 'content', 'depotFile': '//a/b/c.h', 'rev': '42', 'type': 'text', 'depotFile2': '//a/b/c.h', 'rev2': '11', 'type2': 'text'}]
```

How to get which line is added, removed or modified?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tagged version of `p4 diff2` doesn't include the textual diff information, and P4Python enables tagged mode by default.  Do:

```
p4.tagged = False
```

to disable tagged output.

```
import sys
from P4 import P4

p4 = P4()
p4.connect()
p4.tagged = False
for line in p4.run("diff2", sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]):
    print(line) 


C:\Perforce\test>python diff2.py foo bar
==== //stream/main/foo#2 (text) - //stream/main/bar#2 (text) ==== content
1,2c1,2
< asdfasdf
< asdfasdf
---
> asdlfkjasdf
> sdflkj
```